# Vite build fails in Git Actions Pipe: Could not resolve "../Component.tsx" from "../OtherComponent.tsx"

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, github-pages, vite, cicd

So I want to build my React/Vite Project with Github Actions.

So I run bun run build, which triggers vite build [(full workflow)](https://github.com/NkITaa/my-art-onepager/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy.yml):

```
 bun run build -- --mode production
```

Now I get the error that:

```
Could not resolve "./banner/Banner" from "src/pages/home/Home.tsx"
```

Full log:

> Could not resolve "./banner/Banner" from "src/pages/home/Home.tsx"
> file:
> /home/runner/work/my-art-onepager/my-art-onepager/src/pages/home/Home.tsx
> error during build: RollupError: Could not resolve "./banner/Banner"
> from "src/pages/home/Home.tsx"
> at error (file:///home/runner/work/my-art-onepager/my-art-onepager/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30)
> at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///home/runner/work/my-art-onepager/my-art-onepager/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24855:24)
> at file:///home/runner/work/my-art-onepager/my-art-onepager/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24817:26
> error: script "build" exited with code 1 (SIGHUP) Error: Process
> completed with exit code 1.

I thought that maybe I didnt import the banner correctly:

```
import Banner from "./banner/Banner";
```

But all looks good, I also tried:

```
import Banner from "./banner/Banner.tsx";
```

Locally the build works all the time. And when removing the faulty Banner Component (along with some others [in reality the banner isnt the only trigger]) the vite build runs in the pipe.

All the code is available [here](https://github.com/NkITaa/my-art-onepager), the component that imports the triggering components is the [home component](https://github.com/NkITaa/my-art-onepager/blob/main/src/pages/home/Home.tsx), and the triggering imports are the:

- Banner
- Explore
- Infos
- Referals

-> They trigger in this order, so when removing the Banner component the Explore Component triggers the next pipe failure etc.

I have many other components as well that run perfectly, it just seems to be that some of the components that I use in the home component let the build fail.

What could be the cause for this behaviour?